# Как сделать событие правильное событие, которые переплетаются вместе?

Tags: vue.js

У меня есть селект https://codesandbox.io/s/n51o5vww0m, который конфликтует 2 событии, это в теге "li" click и для input событии blur. Но blur мне необходим для того, что если вдруг указал tab, то она после вывода она уходит и не дает выбрать одну запись из списка в li. Как правильно построить этот момент?

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input type="text" />
    <div :class="['select-app', 'base-select']">
      <div ref="selected" :class="['select-app', 'base-select']">
        <input
          @focus="disabled = true;"
          @blur="closeOption"
          type="text"
          :value="name"
          @mousedown="onClick"
          :placeholder="inputPlaceholder"
        />

        <transition name="fade">
          <ul v-show="disabled">
            <li
              v-for="option in options"
              @click="checkOption(option);"
              :class="{ active: option.id === id }"
              class="li-custom"
            >
              <span>{{ option.name }}</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </transition>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
let option = [{ id: 1, name: "hello" }, { id: 1, name: "goodbye" }];
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      name: null,
      id: null,
      disabled: false,
      options: option,
      placeholder: "text"
    };
  },
  watch: {
    value(value) {
      if (typeof value === "object") {
        this.id = value.id;
        this.name = value.name;
      }
    },
    reset(value) {
      if (value) {
        this.name = null;
        this.id = null;

        this.$emit("reset-on");
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    inputPlaceholder() {
      //Формируем placeholder для input
      if (this.placeholder) {
        if (this.description) {
          return this.placeholder;
        }
        return `Выберите ${this.placeholder.toLowerCase()}`;
      } else {
        //Если имеется value, то заносим его, если нет, то вставляем первую запись
        this.name = this.value ? this.value.name : this.options[0].name;
        this.id = this.value ? this.value.id : this.options[0].id;
        return null;
      }
    },
    checkIcon() {
      if (this.id) {
        let icon = this._.filter(this.$props.options, { id: this.id });
        return icon[0].icon;
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    iconWidth(icon) {
      if (
        icon === "radio_button_checked" ||
        icon === "arrow_drop_down_circle"
      ) {
        return "19px";
      } else if (icon === "access_time") {
        return "20px";
      } else {
        return "17px";
      }
    },
    iconHeight(icon) {
      if (icon === "notes") {
        return "11px";
      } else if (icon === "check_box") {
        return "17px";
      } else {
        return "20px";
      }
    },
    closeOption() {
      if (this.disabled) {
        this.disabled = false;
      }
    },
    onClick() {
      this.disabled = !this.disabled;
    },
    checkOption(value) {
      this.name = value.name;
      this.id = value.id;
      this.disabled = false;
      this.$emit("select-value", { id: value.id, name: value.name });
    }
  },
  created() {
    const value = this.value;
    if (value) {
      this.id = value.id;
      this.name = value.name;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="<style" lang="scss">
show-select {
  width: 200px !important;

  input {
    width: 200px !important;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    padding: 9px 16px 10px 16px;

    font-family: "Montserrat";
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #333333;
  }

  ul {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(28, 40, 61, 0.3) !important;
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    max-height: 203px;
    overflow: auto;

    li {
      height: auto !important;
      padding-top: 7px !important;
      padding-bottom: 7px !important;
      padding-left: 16px;
      padding-right: 16px;

      span {
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
        font-family: "Montserrat";
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 500;
        font-style: normal;
        font-stretch: normal;
        line-height: normal;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        text-align: right;
        color: #333333;
      }
    }

    li:hover {
      background: rgba(8, 111, 190, 0.1) !important;

      span {
        color: #086fbe;
      }
    }

    .active {
      background: rgba(8, 111, 190, 0.1) !important;

      span {
        color: #086fbe;
      }
    }
  }
}

.select-app {
  width: 310px;
  position: relative;

  .select {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }

  ul,
  input {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  input {
    outline: none;
  }

  .icon-input {
    position: absolute;
    left: 19px;
    color: #b7bbc0;
  }

  .error {
    border: 1px solid #ec3030;
  }

  .icon_drop-down {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 19px;
    left: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #b7bbc0;

    & span {
    }
  }

  .icon_drop-down-base {
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    right: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #b7bbc0;
  }

  .icon-field_text {
    padding-left: 51px;
  }

  ul {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #fefefe;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px 0 rgba(185, 185, 185, 0.8);
    border-radius: 4px;
    max-height: 203px;
    overflow: auto;

    li {
      padding: 0 20px;
      height: 30px;
      line-height: 30px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;

      .svg-icon {
        color: #b7bbc0;
      }

      &:hover {
        background: rgba(8, 111, 190, 0.1);
        color: #086fbe;

        span {
          color: #086fbe;
        }

        .svg-icon {
          color: #086fbe;
        }
      }
    }

    &.bottom-select {
      bottom: -15px;
    }

    &.top-select {
      top: 0;
    }

    span {
      //padding: 0 15px;
    }

    .active {
      /*background: #f7f7f7;*/
      background: rgba(8, 111, 190, 0.1);

      span {
        color: #086fbe;
      }
    }
  }
}

.li-custom {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  svg {
    /*margin-right: 10px;*/
    width: 22px !important;
    height: 22px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  span {
    line-height: 15px;
  }

  &:hover {
    svg {
      color: #086fbe !important;
    }
  }

  &.active {
    svg {
      color: #086fbe !important;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: можно было бы код еще и здесь выложить

Comment: Обновил описание

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем варианте можно сделать проверку на blure выбран ли вариант, если нет, то не прятать его.

```
   closeOption() {
      if (this.disabled && this.name) {
        this.disabled = false;
      }
```

Comment: Это работает только один раз, второй раз уже не выбирается ничего. Наверное ближайшее решение это сделать mousedown.prevent вместо клика. Но не знаю правильно это или нет

Comment: Так в вопрос стоял: `она уходит и не дает выбрать одну запись из списка в li` а запись уже выбрана. Сбрасывайте ее при повторном входе

Comment: Там есть свои минусы, если я ничего не выбрал, то значение сброситься. Наверное проще использовать mousedown

Comment: Я понимаю что это грубо но вот так работает `@focus="disabled = true; name = ''"` При входе все обнуляется и пока не выберешь значение не закрывается